# i cant find my mistake on my software (switch on C language)

Tags: c, switch-statement

this is my first post here.
i started learning software engineering this month and i'm tring to code a software using c.
i cant found the mistake to change it ..
can anyone help me please!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int a,b,e;
        char operation;
        printf ("enter the first number:");
        scanf ("%d",&a);
        printf ("enter the second number:");
        scanf ("%d",&b);
        printf ("enter the operation:");
        scanf ("%c", &operation);
        switch (operation)
        {   case '+' :  e=a+b;
            break;
            case '-' :  e=a-b;
            break;
            case '*' :  e=a*b;
            break;
            case '/' :  e=a/b;
            break;
            default: printf("wrong choice!!");
    
        }

    printf("%d %c %d = %d \n", a, operation, b, e);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you receive when you try to execute your program?

Comment: Hint: Examine the value of `c`

Comment: C:\Users\JAOUADI\Desktop\C>max
enter the first number:5
enter the second number:6
enter the operation:wrong choice!!5
 6 = 464950

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read  [ask]. Your questin leaves too much to guessing. It is basically "Hi. Code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Oka [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

You have to discard the newline character, you can simply use `getchar()` function before the last `scanf` to discard that single character (could be newline char or not), to be 100% sure about discarding all the unread characters from input buffer you can do

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

Or else can use `" %c"` (whitespace %c) to ignore the leading newline character.

Comment: thank you <3 i'm new here i can't upvote :/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int a,b,e;
        char operation;
        printf ("enter the first number:");
        scanf ("%d",&a);
        printf ("enter the second number:");
        scanf ("%d",&b);
        getchar();
        printf ("enter the operation:");
        scanf ("%c", &operation);
        switch (operation)
        {   case '+' :  e=a+b;
            break;
            case '-' :  e=a-b;
            break;
            case '*' :  e=a*b;
            break;
            case '/' :  e=a/b;
            break;
            default: printf("wrong choice!!");
    
        }

    printf("%d %c %d = %d \n", a, operation, b, e);
    }
```

your `scanf ("%c", &operation);` is reading a **newline character** `\n` from the above scanf statement. so, to scan the operation statement properly you have to add `getchar()` which detect the **newline character** `\n`.

Comment: thank you <3

i'm new here i can't upvote :/